# Why is this Procedural Content Generation while that other isn't?

Tags: procedural-generation, terminology, content-generation

I'm reading the [online Procedural Content Generation book](http://pcgbook.com/wp-content/uploads/chapter01.pdf) and on chapter 1, page 2 there's one example of what PCG is and another of what PCG is not and I can't tell them apart.

This is PCG according to them:

> game engine middleware that rapidly populates a game world with vegetation

This is NOT PCG according to them:

> a game engine capable of integrating automatically generated vegetation

Also on page 1 they explicitly said they do not consider a game engine PCG

> A key term here is “content”. In our definition, content is most of what is contained in a game: levels, maps, game rules, textures, stories, items, quests, music, weapons, vehicles, characters, etc. **The game engine itself is not considered to be content in our definition.**

My guess is the PCG example is a code in a game (or it could be a code that adapts to any game) that recognizes the game map and populates it with vegetation according to it. And the not PCG example for me would be like an option available from the game engine were the developer can add the vegetation offline via the user interface.

The last one is a very very wild guess from me, I'm pretty sure I'm wrong cause at first glance they both sound like PCG. Please help me differentiate them.

Comment: Compare two men: A walks into a room, looks at it, builds furniture based on the room, and puts the furniture in the room. B does the same, but he goes to IKEA (people who have built the furniture) to get furniture to put in the room. Would you say that both A and B are creating furniture? That's the difference that they're trying to point at. Unless you're creating the furniture from scratch, you're not actually creating furniture, you're just using existing furniture in new ways.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**By way of analogy**

A circuit does not generate power. A light bulb does not generate power. A battery does not generate power. None of the things which *use or store generated power*, are power generators.

A gasoline-driven generator *is a power generator*.
A solar panel setup *is a power generator*. *They* can be expected to spontaneously generate when they are kicked off. Other things can *use* that power they generate: fridges and TVs and PCs and heaters and light bulbs.

Likewise, any code or program that *actually generates content itself at runtime* is PCG. The rest are just *users* of that procedurally-generated content (PGC). Now,

*Procedural Content Generation*

is not the same as

*Procedurally-Generated Content*

PGC is the resultant artifact of a process (program) which engages in PCG.

PCG is developed (programmed) to a point where it can autonomously produce content to some or other specification, but in (typically) countless variations; PGC is generated thereby as *one single* variation of the otherwise limitless possible content spaces within that broader algorithmic specification. PGC's are *finite* and *static* once generated. PCGs deal with *infinity* (or near enough).

**Addressing specifics**

"Procedural Content Generation" refers to code / applications which generate content.

Any game can be considered a PCG game *if, at runtime* it dynamically generates new content via part of its instruction set.

If you (or your engine) use(s) some other program code that generates content, then include that content as part of your game at *compile / build time*, then your game (and it's code) is NOT PCG. Hence:

> a game engine capable of integrating automatically generated vegetation

...is not PCG, since that engine itself does not produce new content at runtime, it simply uses generated content from elsewhere, that has been manually included by artists, designer or devs.

> recognizes the game map

PCG has nothing to do with recognition. It has to do with doing the active work of creating content. Generally PCG applications produce their own format of data that they can already understand and work with. They do not typically read in outside sources, although when they do, that is just plain old program logic... not PCG as such. PCG is all about *generation*. Hence PCG and not PCR :)

**Historical perspectives**

What we consider "content" in this context generally covers those things which, in the past, humans have *had* to produce by themselves. For example in the '70s and '80s, pretty much every game (with the exception of a very special few) had to have its art, its storyline, its music, its character and planet names, and suchlike, produced by a human being. That was the *polar opposite* of PCG.

PCG began when game programmers realised that instead of the rigmarole of hiring artists, musicians, writers etc. - and then still having to integrate their work with the code, or worse yet, doing all of that work themselves *as well as coding* - they could instead write programs to generate all that stuff for them. Those efforts were some of the first truly PCG functions, modules, and programs. A perfect example is the [original XCom / UFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOM:_Enemy_Unknown), where the game's code generates a completely unique level for you before combat. Earlier still (1979) was [Temple of Apshai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_of_Apshai).

[Elite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elite_(video_game)) was a different case: *some* of its content was generated when the game was under development; not only was that code written by the very same authors, but also that pre-generated content was typically used at runtime of `elite.exe` (i.e. when you the player ran the game) by *further generators which were part of the game's code*, creating the world you played in.

A newer example is [Minecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft) (and other games inspired by it) where the world literally generates around you as you walk toward the horizon, thanks in large part to modern computing power. Compare this to [Rogue or Moria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(video_game)) played on a PC-XT in the 1980s, for which you might have to sit sometime waiting for the level to generate! (depending on your chosen game settings).

Not all PCG is historically rooted in the games industry. For example, there are those who write fiction generators. For example, Ken Perlin in the field of graphics and computational geometry created the Perlin Noise algorithm, for which he was later given an academy award. For example, the musician Brian Eno has for a long time engaged in procedural generation of musical scores. And as another example, non-digital boardgames like HeroQuest/Warhammer Quest long ago invented procedural dynamics for creating a different gameboard on each play.

Comment: `If you (or your engine) uses some other program code that generates content, and then include that content as part of your game at compile / build time, your game (and it's code) is NOT PCG`. How so? Isn't that the definition of Offline Content Generation? PCG can be used, for example, to help a level designer. The generator can create a level on the development face which the designer can later tweak and fix any issues with it.

Comment: @Adocad _Specifically for the reason that your game or engine is NOT generating content at RUNtime._ As noted in my Elite example, you may well have your own 3rd party or proprietary generators in place to _assist_ you in creation of what will ultimately be a _static content game_, but that _game_ will not be a Procedural Content Generator in itself. The reason Elite was _still_ PCG was that it did _also_ do runtime generation, using preconfigured parameters.

Comment: If, BTW, you are referring to static or dynamic libraries linked into your code, that is a whole other technical and legal discussion which really boils down to "who wrote what, and who owns what" . The above is the standard definition, and PCGWiki is quite correct in their definition.

Comment: A very minor technical exception - there was a proof of concept research project/game in which the game itself was procedurally generated. That is, the goals, rules and to some extent, the representation were all dynamically generated at run time. It blurs the line between content & engine somewhat, but the litmus test of "does it generate" still holds even there. Excellent distillation.

Comment: @Pikalek I agree fully with that line of thinking. We can take it as far as Lisp does - that there ultimately is no distinction between instructions and data. Didn't want to over-complicate things in the answer though. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @Arcane with PCGWiki are you referring to http://pcg.wikidot.com/? because they don't state that the generation must be done at runtime. And every other site/paper I see specifies that offline generation is still procedural content generation, even if it's during the development phase. Let's just assume I coded my own PCG for the example above; creating maps during development that I'll later have to tweak... I appreciate the help, but I still don't see why offline generation is not PCG

Comment: @adocad Of course it's procedural generation! But your code _using_ it is _not._ You cannot claim to know much about PCG code when all you have done is use someone else's tool. That is like me using AWS and claiming I know about big / scalable data. I do not. Or using a GIS library and claiming to know how to implement a GIS. Accept that you are using someone else's expertise, and that at the end of the day, just as if you had writers and artists and musicians working on your game, your game will still not be procedural if it did not generate its own dynamic content at runtime: It is _static_.

Comment: @Adocad: I think you missed a minor detail in the answer: _"If you (or your engine) uses some other **program code that generates content**, and then include that **content** as part of your game at compile / build time, your game (and it's code) is NOT PCG"_ If you had included the program in your game, instead of the content that was generated by the program, and your game would trigger the program when it needed to (locally, on a player's computer), then it would indeed be offline PCG. But that is not the case when you simply include a result from a PCG generation (which is now static).

Comment: Perhaps it's worth making a distinction between procedurally generated content (PGC -- the "offline", compiled-in variety) and procedural content generation (PCG -- the "runtime" flavor in question).  PGC just helps the game makers save time and money spent on e.g. artists by using tools to help content generation.  PCG is a technique that allows a game to offer new content on every playthrough, generate boundless dynamic worlds,  etc.

Comment: @AC: I think the distinction is clearer when labeling it as either _procedurally generated content_ or _procedural content generation_.

Comment: @A C, Flater I have included this distinction at the end of the question, as yes it needed addressing explicitly. Thanks to you both for the advice.

Comment: @Flater Thanks, that's a better way of putting it -- procedurally generated content can be generated offline and/or at runtime, but *procedural content generation* is explicitly runtime.  (Note that a *tool* which generates content which will later be compiled in *is* doing PCG, however after that content has been pre-generated and compiled in, the game that uses that content is *NOT* doing PCG)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Sorry for the late response but the difference is crystal clear now

Comment: Any discussion of procedural content generation in Elite is incomplete without a link to [txtelite](https://github.com/fragglet/txtelite), which includes source code for a C version of the content generation routines that were used in the game.